# Replacing a bathroom fan - two ground wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, ground

I've purchased a Broan NuTone fan to replace the old one in my bathroom. The fan itself has a white wire, a black wire and a green wire. The wiring in my house consists of a black wire, a white wire, a green wire and a bare copper ground.

According to the instructions, I am to attach the green wire from the fan to either a green wire from the supply or to the ground. Since the existing wiring includes both, should I connect both the green and the bare copper to the green wire attached to the fan?

Comment: Are the green and the bare in your box connected? Are there two sets of wires in your box or just one plus the green? I would assume the green fan wire goes to the bare ground, but? Photos of the inside of your box may help.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: what do the install instructions say?

Comment: Is the fan of the type that "if you turn it on, it turns on both the light and the fan, always both on" (and the one you are replacing you could turn on one or the other separately?)